# wpf - ContainerFromItem returning null in set method but works fine in get method

Tags: wpf

I have created a checked ListBox in WF using an item template.
 here is the xaml code for that.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="datatemplate_List">
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel_List" Orientation="Horizontal"  >
            <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox_List" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="22"/>
            <Label x:Name="label_List" Height="18" FontSize="12" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.Content}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I also have another usercontrol which has this checked listbox inside of it. this usercontrol has a property which gets and sets the checkboxes of the checked listbox.  the get function returns a list of all the checked items and this function preforms correctly, the set function unchecks all the items in the listbox then only checks the ones that are checked in the value.

```
 public List<string> measurements
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> measList = new List<string>();
            //foreach (string chkBox in chkListBox_Meas.CheckedItems) measList.Add(chkBox); marks code

            for (int i = 0; i < chkListBox_Meas.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(chkListBox_Meas.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(chkListBox_Meas.Items[i]));
                ContentPresenter contentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(listBoxItem);
                DataTemplate dataTemplate = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
                StackPanel stack = (StackPanel)dataTemplate.FindName("stackpanel_List", contentPresenter);
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)stack.FindName("checkbox_List");
                Label label = (Label)stack.FindName("label_List");
                if (checkBox.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    measList.Add(label.Content.ToString());
                }
            }
            return measList;
        }

         set
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < chkListBox_Meas.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)chkListBox_Meas.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(chkListBox_Meas.Items[i]);
                ContentPresenter contentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(listBoxItem);
                DataTemplate dataTemplate = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
                StackPanel stack = (StackPanel)dataTemplate.FindName("stackpanel_List", contentPresenter);
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)stack.FindName("checkbox_List");
                checkBox.IsChecked = false;
            }

            foreach (string meas in value)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < chkListBox_Meas.Items.Count; i++)
                {

                    ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(chkListBox_Meas.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(chkListBox_Meas.Items[i]));
                    ContentPresenter contentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(listBoxItem);
                    DataTemplate dataTemplate = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
                    StackPanel stack = (StackPanel)dataTemplate.FindName("stackpanel_List", contentPresenter);
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)stack.FindName("checkbox_List");
                    Label label = (Label)stack.FindName("label_List");

                    if (label.Content.ToString() == meas) checkBox.IsChecked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem occurs when I execute this line of code.
 `ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem chkListBox_Meas.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(chkListBox_Meas.Items[i]);`

when this is executed in the get function it returns a listboxitem as it is suppose to. but when this line is executed in the set function it is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason Why the `ListBoxItem` is returning a `null` value is because the `ItemContainerGenerator` which the line

```
ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(chkListBox_Meas.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(chkListBox_Meas.Items[i]));
```

Is trying to access has not been generated yet.

The solution is to call the `ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged` Event Handler and wait for the status to changed to `ContainerGenerated`. Once that happens you will be able to access the `ListBoxItem`